# It would be possible to visualize the value of the integral together with the graph (in the same Manipulate command)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate, scoping

```
f[x_, y_] := x - 3 y Manipulate[RegionPlot[ 0 <= x <= a && 0 <= y <= b (1 - (x/a)), {x, 0, a + 2}, {y, 0, b + 2}], {a, 1, 20, 1}, {b, 1, 20, 1}]
```

I would like to show with `Manipulate`, apart from the domain (which is what I have done as it can be seen), also the integral of the function with `Manipulate`, changing the values `a` and `b`, if it is posible.

I think it is easy, but I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Manipulate[
 int = NIntegrate[x - 3 y, {x, 0, a + 2}, {y, 0, b + 2}];
 RegionPlot[
  0 <= x <= a && 0 <= y <= b (1 - (x/a)), {x, 0, a + 2}, {y, 0, 
   b + 2}, Epilog -> 
   Inset[Row[{Style["J=", 14, Black, Italic], 
      Style[int, 14, Black, Italic]}], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]],
 {a, 1, 20, 1}, {b, 1, 20, 1}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I have a doubt. I am starting with the program, but if J is the value of the integral, how can it be possible that the integral, that represents the value of an area, has a minus  sign? Thank you

Comment: And also, for example, if you give to a and b the values 1 and 1, the value of the integral i think it should be -1/3 ( because the solution of the integration is a^2 b)/6 - (a b^2)/2), and if I am not wrong, doing what you have told me, j takes the value -27.

Comment: It is because you asked to include an integral of the function of two variables, but you did not write that you want that it should be the area. Then you need another integral, a quite standard one,  yielding the surface area. You can write it yourself, while the principle of how one can show it together with the plot stays the same as in the example that I published.

Comment: Ok understood, thank you for your time and for your help.